# Does calling a destructor explicitly destroy an object completely?

Tags: c++, destructor

If I call a destructor explicitly (  myObject.~Object() ) does this assure me that the object will be appropriately destroyed (calling all child destructors) ?

Ok some code:

```
class Object
{
   virtual ~Object()
   {}
};

class Widget : public Object
{
   virtual ~Widget()
   {}
};

...
Object* aWidget = new Widget(); //allocate and construct
aWidget->~Object(); //destroy and DON'T deallocate
```

I know I could just delete the object, but I don't want to. I want to keep the allocated memory handy as an important optimization.

Thanks!

Comment: this implementation is for the memory manager, the client never sees/uses this as such. The manager does it behind the scenes.

Comment: Just don't abuse your code this way.  If you want to allocate memory then allocate memory.

Comment: Have you proved that this is actually an "important optimization"?

Comment: Thanks for all the answers, I left the context of my implementation very vague, but thats because its actually irrelevant, since my question is simply if a base destructor when called explicitly will chain call all its child class destructors or not. Anyways the code will be hidden from the end-user by a source/sink interface, so the user only needs to ask and return objects to the library.

Comment: Applying this optimization, gives a decent performance boost, and avoids calling the kernel and fragmenting memory, for a long lived application, and if the destructor does what I want, and it does, the implementation is fairly trivial, so its a good sound optimization with little developer overhead, etc...

Comment: "I left the context of my implementation very vague, but thats because its actually irrelevant" - that depends of whether you want to receive good advice from this community.  The direct answer to your question trivial - "yes, so long as the destructor is virtual".  A better answer is, "Why are you opening this can of whoop-ass"?  Ie, give me some very important and relevant context to the question.

Comment: I think there is some hidden complication here: We know that delete on a base* that actually points to a derived is undefined behavior if the dtor is non-virtual. but what about an explicit destructor call ala' b->~base(); ? I don't know whether this is undefined behavior, or whether it's defined behavior (in that it only destructs a base-class sub-object well-behaved).

Comment: That is another good point I'd not considered directly! There seems to be something inherently dubious about destructor calls, but as Max Lybbert pointed out std::allocator does exactly this within destroy so it seems like it should be defined behavior

Comment: I think what you propose will give well defined behaviour, but I'm not sure if you can have correct behaviour with this scheme.  If you new an object normally, for correctness that object must eventually be deleted otherwise you have a leak.  However delete will call the destructor so if you have already done this, you have a double destructor call which is incorrect behaviour.  It just doesn't seem right to me.  I think you should seriously consider separating allocation/deallocation and construction/destruction using the tools provided by the language - placement new or class new/delete.

Comment: std::allocator knows that stuff points to T when it does ~T().

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The answer is... nearly always.

If your object has a non-virtual destructor, and is then sub-classed to add child elements that need freeing... then calling the destructor on the object base class will not free the child elements.  This is why you should always declare destructors virtual.

We had an interesting case where two shared libraries referenced an object.  We changed the definition to add child objects which needed freeing.  We recompiled the first shared library which contained the object definition.

HOWEVER, the second shared library was not recompiled.  This means that it did not know of the newly added virtual object definition.  Delete's invoked from the second shared library simply called free, and did not invoke the virtual destructor chain.  Result was a nasty memory leak.

Comment: Good point, but your problem was caused by not recompiling enough libraries :-)

Comment: Good point :) But still no need to always declare a destructor virtual. Only needed when you are utilizing polymorphism.

Comment: don't just throw around virtual for no reason: http://www.slideshare.net/olvemaudal/deep-c/345

Comment: *"If your object has a non-virtual destructor, and is then sub-classed to add child elements that need freeing..."* - I *thought* if at least one dtor was marked virtual, then all would be virtual (modulo the recompile). Is that not the case? Or does that only apply to member functions?

Comment: @jww, _"if at least one dtor was marked virtual, then all would be virtual"_ No, marking the derived destructor as virtual does not make the base destructor virtual. That's the same as other member functions.

Answer (score 10):

Yes. But holy smokes, are you sure about this? If so I would use [placement `new`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222557/cs-placement-new) to construct your `Widget`. Using placement `new` and then explicitly calling the destructor is an acceptable, if unusual, idiom.

**Edit**: Consider allocating the memory yourself manually rather than using `new` to allocate the first object and then re-using its memory afterward. That allows you complete control over the memory; you could allocate big chunks at a time, for instance, rather than allocating a separate block of memory for each `Widget`. That'd be fair savings if memory really is such a scarce resource.

Also, and perhaps more importantly, you'd then be doing placement `new` "normally", rather than this hybrid regular `new`/placement `new` solution. I'm not saying it won't work, I'm just saying it's a rather, ah, *creative* solution to your memory problem.

Comment: Yeah I know the code as such is not very intuitive, but the memory handling happens behind a source/sink pattern, so the user just requests widgets, they get newed if there are none left, and they get a placement new if there is memory left.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, a destructor, even when called explicitly, will destroy its subobjects properly.

As you seem to realize, it's a rare action to do, but perhaps as part of a well tested and documented library it may be useful.  But document (and profile) it since even though it's valid and safe, every maintainer (including you) will never feel comfortable with it.

Answer (score 6):

Yes it will call all the child destructors so it will work as you are expecting.

The destructor is just a function after all, it just so happens that it gets called when objects **are deleted**.

Therefore if you use this approach be careful of this:

```
#include <iostream>

class A
{
public: 
    A(){};
    ~A()
    {
        std::cout << "OMG" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    A* a = new A;
    a->~A();
    delete a;
    return 0;
}

output:
OMG
OMG
```

The destructor is called a second time when delete is actually called on the object, so if you delete pointers in your destructor, make sure that you set them to 0, so that the second the destructor is called nothing will happen (as deleting a null pointer does nothing).

Answer (score 5):

Please save yourself some real headaches and use the [Boost Object Pool](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/libs/pool/doc/index.html), which sounds like an existing implementation of your source/sink pattern. It will allocate large chunks of memory, slice them into the correct size for your object and return them to you (after calling the constructor). When you delete objects, they have their destructor called and are put into a linked list of objects for re-use. It will grow and shrink automatically and ensure that instances of your objects tend to be close together in memory.

If nothing else, it is a good example implementation of placement new and explicit use of constructors that you could study.

Comment: I wish, but I can't use boost. Anyways I'll look at the implementation

Answer (score 3):

Yes.  A destructor calls any member destructors in LIFO order, then base class destructors, and there is no way to *prevent* it from calling these destructors*.  The object stack is guaranteed to unwind.

Initialization and finalization are separated from memory allocation and deallocation in C++ exactly so that when the special case arises, there is an unambiguous syntax in which the application-programmer can express his or her intent to the compiler.

Edit:

- I suppose that by invoking abort() or longjmp() one could, in fact, prevent the member and base class destructors from running.

Answer (score 2):

Running the destructor does not free memory used by the object being destructed - the delete operator does that.  Note, however, that the destructor may delete "child objects" and their memory will be freed as per usual.

You need to read up on placement new/delete as this allows you to control memory allocation and when constructors/destructors run.

See here for a little info:

```
http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/dtors.html#faq-11.9
```

Comment: I know, I know, I DON'T want to free the memory, I just want to destroy the object.

Comment: ok, ok - use placement new to match your explicit call to the destructor.  I don't understand why you can't reuse the old widget, assigning new values to its members.  Why construct and destruct as you are doing?  For example, if you are just trying to avoid the heap allocation, allocate your new widget on the stack and then assign (operator ==) to the existing widget that was heap allocated.

Comment: The issue is I need to call the destructor, because it happens to do non trivial things if widget gets subclasses

Comment: How can your approach possibly work if Widget can be subclassed?  The subclasses would, under most circumstances, be different sizes.  It feels like you're playing with fire with this approach.

Comment: Because the subclassing of widget is limited to the library code, not user code, and widgets of each type are stored in different pools, so the size of a determined widget family will not change (except for the recompile issue pointed above)

Comment: Ok, so the type of Widget is the final class.  Tell me why you need to run destructors and constructors rather than using an assignment operator?  Also, why are you allocating individual Widgets?  Surely a std::vector< Widget > (not a std::vector< Widget* > ) and the use of assignments would give you the optimisation you are looking for.

Comment: ... correction - perhaps a std::deque<Widget> as the vector requires the elements to be relocatable, which is not true when you are return points to the elements to calling code.

Comment: yeah the std::vector won't cut it. Anyways the idea of delegating the whole business to a deque is something I had considered, because its a good idea, but to deepen my knowledge of C++ I began investigating this perhaps, unorthodox solution.

Answer (score 2):

STL containers do this.  In fact, an STL allocator must provide a destroy method that calls an object's destructor (allcators also provide a deallocate method to deallocate the memory that used to hold an object).  However, the advice from Stroustrup (*The C++ Programming Language* 10.4.11) is

> Note that explicit calls of destructors ... should be avoided wherever possible.  Occassionally, they are essential. ...  A novice should think thrice before calling a destructor explicitly and also ask a more experienced colleague before doing so.

Comment: In all fairness - asking more experienced people is basically what he's doing.

Comment: Yeah I've been bit by this behavior in STL containers, which is why I was wondering about the implementation details

Answer (score 1):

Calling the destructor is fine. However, beware of the type you're calling it on. If that type doesn't have (didn't inherit) a virtual destructor, you might get unexpected behaviour.

Also, as mentioned, the destructor does not free any memory, but I guess that's the reason you want to call it manually in the first place.

Plus, unless I'm mistaken, calling the destructor manually is the only option you have if you used placement new to call the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Why destroy it at all?  Just write over the memory?  Are you wanting logic to execute to gracefully handle releasing resources?  I am going to state emphatically that this is an abuse of the language and not a good idea.

Comment: Opinion noted, but this does not answer the question.

Comment: Thanks for the preoccupation, but my question is a very fundamental question, and if the behavior is not depending on undefined behavior, or compiler dependent implementations, it should be perfectly valid, as strange as it may be.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider overriding new for the objects you want special allocation and deallocation behaviour for - after all that's what it's for.  A hybrid scheme of normal new and explicitly calling destructors sounds like a recipe for future headaches.  For starters, any memory leak detection strategy is going to get thrown way off.