# How do I delete memory after manually invoking destructor?

Tags: c++, memory

I was reading this question [Does calling a destructor explicitly destroy an object completely?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1036019/857994) where this situation comes up in code.

```
Object* aWidget = new Widget(); //allocate and construct
aWidget->~Object();             //destroy and DON'T deallocate
```

From the answers, I undrestand that the memory region is in fact not deallocated in this situation.  My question is (more out of curiosity than anything):

How can I delete the memory pointed to by aWidget after the two lines of code above have executed?  I would assume calling `delete aWidget;` would fail because it would try to run the destructor on an already-destructed object.  Could you call `free(aWidget)` or something like that instead to just target the memory?

Comment: I'm not certain so I'm posting as a comment, but you may be able to call `operator delete(aWidget)`. I'd be curious to see code that ran into this as a valid use case, though!

Comment: @CoryNelson you're right, see my answer. I was typing it as you posted the comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`free` would, factually speaking, be my best guess. However I don't think you can do *anything* without invoking UB. How did you arrive at a requirement to invoke the destructor like that?

Comment: I didn't actually, I was just reading the question I cited and got curious about how they'd fix the situation they walked into.  I have seen destructor calls like this in programs using placement new though.

Comment: @w00te: Yea, it's different with placement new ;)

Answer (score 1):

Calling `free` on an object allocated with `new` is **undefined behavior**.

I suggest you keep it simple, and call `delete`.

However, if you want to do this, you *can*, in some cases, call `delete` even if you previously called the destructor explicitly. If you call it explicitly, you can view it as a function. The memory isn't freed, so I'm guessing setting member pointers to `NULL` after you destroy them would be enough to prevent you from running into any trouble. (because calling `delete` on a `NULL` pointer is a no-op).

For example, the following should be ok:

```
class A
{
public:
    int * x;
    A() 
    { 
        x = new int[10]; 
    }
    ~A() 
    { 
        delete[] x; 
        x = NULL; 
    }
};

int main()
{
    A* a = new A;
    a->~A();
    delete a;
    return 0;
}
```