# How use .lib and .h in c#

Tags: c#, c++, dll

I have .lib and .h but do not have their source, so the wrapper does not offer. I need to use objects from .lib .h C#

```
struct Node: public Nown{
    virtual NMRESULT            Get(Nodeip** ppNodeip)=0;
    virtual NMRESULT            Load(LPCSTR Name,char** Value=0,int Count=0)=0;
};
```

example code, how i can use this?

Comment: I don't like using `Call C++ library in C# `, because it is an "old style" response: link only.

Comment: Another link is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29764548/call-c-native-unmanaged-member-functions-from-c-sharp-when-member-functions-we, there I responded to a similar question. Note that you can't create the `Node` from C#: you need to have a method in the library that creates the `Node` for you (and normally there is another method that destroys it)

Comment: Ah and note that you can't link directly a `.lib` file to a C# program: you need a `dll`.

Comment: how to call a function of the type long Nown::Create(char const*, char const*, void**, long) in c#?